# How do I include types from a gem with sigs?

Tags: sorbet

Let's say I have a shared gem called `thing` that gets used in multiple other projects, like `example-project`. I want to use sorbet in my `thing` gem to take advantage of the type checking. How do I get my consuming projects to check against the types in my gem?

For example, the code might look like this

**thing gem**

```rb
# typed: strict

require 'sorbet-runtime'

class Thing
  extend T::Sig

  sig { params(phrase: String).returns(String) }
  def say(phrase)
    "Thing said: '#{phrase}'"
  end
end
```

**example-project**

```rb
# typed: strict

require 'thing'

Thing.new.say(1) # Should cause a type error
```

### What happens

After running `srb rbi update`, I get an `sorbet/rbi/gems/thing.rbi`

```rb
class Thing
  def say(*args, &blk); end
  extend T::Private::Methods::MethodHooks
  extend T::Private::Methods::SingletonMethodHooks
  extend T::Sig
end
```

This doesn't have the sigs from the gem that I'm expecting, and `srb tc` doesn't raise the error I'm expecting.

### Other things I've tried

#### Including `rbi/thing.rbi` in the gem

This works, but I'd rather write my sigs inline in the gem code than maintain separate rbi files.  Is there any tooling that could take the `.rb` files with sigs and output the `.rbi` files (and maybe strip the sigs from the `.rb` files so them gem can be distributed without sorbet). I'm thinking of a workflow similar to typescript's `tsc --declaration`, which goes from `.ts => .d.ts + .js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/AaronC81/brain_freeze
is a new project that aims to make it possible to generate an RBI file from RB files with inline declarations. It's still early, but might be worth trying out

Comment: Great! Looks like this is trying to solve exactly my use case.